# MOV file contains data from "Apple Elementary video MPEG-2 Media Handler" codec. How do I access it in current MacOS?

Tags: codec, conversion, mpeg

I am helping a director access an archive file of a documentary. The file is presented as a 3GB MOV.

FFmpeg indicates the following:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2011-02-06T03:17:28.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.gain: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.treble: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.bass: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.balance: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.pitchshift: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.mute: 
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.brightness: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.color: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.tint: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.contrast: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.version: 7.6.9 (7.6.9)
    com.apple.quicktime.version: 7.6.9 (1680.9) 0x7698000 (Mac OS X, 10.5.8, 9L31a)
  Duration: 00:50:17.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8539 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-02-06T03:17:28.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (m2v  / 0x2076326D) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-02-06T03:17:28.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple elementary video MPEG-2 Media Handler
```

The bitrate and duration of the file indicates there is definitely data in the video stream, although it can't be accessed.

From research, it appears that the "Apple elementary video MPEG-2 Media Handler" was the (very) old quicktime MPEG-2 component that was active in early versions of quicktime, but is now no longer supported in current versions of MacOS.

So, how do I get access to the vision in this file?

Comment: Pure guesswork.. Maybe QT7 - https://support.apple.com/kb/dl923?locale=en_GB or for Windows - https://support.apple.com/kb/dl837?locale=en_GB Or even QT6, no idea how safe this link is - https://www.macintoshrepository.org/2473-quicktime-6-0-3 nor do I know what these will run on. You might end up needing a VM to get them running.

Comment: Have you tried viewing it in VLC?  https://www.videolan.org/vlc/  sometimes it can play codecs that other players can't?  Also Blender has a built in video editor that sometimes can render files QuickTime / Adobe products won't in my experience. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/introduction.html